Lifetime mismatch when implementing trait method with lifetime parameter
I'm trying to implement the LogRecord trait for the LogRecordImpl struct, but I'm running into a lifetime mismatch error. Here's my code:
use std::borrow::Cow;

pub trait LogRecord {
    fn set_body<'a>(&mut self, body: AnyValue<'a>);
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
pub enum AnyValue<'a> {
    Int(i64),
    Double(f64),
    String(Cow<'a, str>),
}

// ... (other code)

#[derive(Debug, Default, Clone, PartialEq)]
pub struct LogRecordImpl<'a> {
    pub body: Option<AnyValue<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> LogRecord for LogRecordImpl<'a> {
    fn set_body(&mut self, body: AnyValue<'a>) {
        self.body = Some(body);
    }
}

Playground
I'm getting the following error:
error[E0308]: method not compatible with trait
  --> src/lib.rs:74:5
   |
74 |     fn set_body(&mut self, body: AnyValue<'a>)
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected signature `fn(&mut LogRecordImpl<'_>, AnyValue<'a>)`
              found signature `fn(&mut LogRecordImpl<'_>, AnyValue<'a>)`
note: the lifetime `'a` as defined here...
  --> src/lib.rs:74:5
   |
74 |     fn set_body(&mut self, body: AnyValue<'a>)
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...does not necessarily outlive the lifetime `'a` as defined here
  --> src/lib.rs:73:6
   |
73 | impl<'a> LogRecord for LogRecordImpl<'a> {
   |      ^^

I don't want to add the lifetime specifier on the LogRecord trait, but only on the methods declared within it.

You can't use anything but exactly fn set_body<'a>(&mut self, AnyValue<'a>) as the signature in your impl

Yes, but that gives another error error[E0496]: lifetime name ``'a`` shadows a lifetime name that is already in scope.

Then, … use another name for one of the lifetimes.

does it make sense for your usage to change LogRecord to LogRecord<'a>, and make set_body<'a>(..) to set_body(..)

@啊鹿Dizzyi I think the last sentence of the post explicitly says this is not wanted.

@cafce25 tried fn set_body<'b>(&mut self, body: AnyValue<'b>) {}  and  fn set_body<'b>(&mut self, body: AnyValue<'b>) where 'b: 'a {} both doesn't work

The second obviously, it's a different signature! The first failing probably means that the trait doesn't allow you to do what you want to. The trait essentially says, nothing in self holds on to the body after the function returns, assigning self.body = body obviously violates that promise.

Or alternatively you can read the signature as "references in body: AnyValue<'a> are valid for the duration of the call" and doesn't guarantee anything more.

Yes, that's a good point. This means that I need to add lifetime specifier to LogRecord trait, something I was trying to avoid :)
